# CNContact add new contact issue

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

I'm faccing an issue at time of adding contacts throught **Contact Framework**.

I used device iPhone 5s with iOS 12.1.2

My Code for adding contact is as below ::

```
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.add(self, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
do {
    try contactStore.execute(saveRequest)
} catch let error {
    print("Error occurred while saving the request \(error)")
}
```

This everytime thows error as below ::

> Error occurred while saving the request Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=1 "Communication Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication Error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An error occurred while trying to communicate with the Contacts service.}

Dose any one now anything about this error?

I'm not able to found any thing about this.

Comment: what was the issue and how you resolved it

Comment: The issue is the CNContactStore initialization method, I used to init it every time I come to the view before calling and saving the request. So I changed this to the singleton of the same an the issue had been resolved. Please try this if you have the same issue.

Comment: can you please please give me the solution of singelton please?????

Comment: sure will add it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the singleton for the `CNcibtactStore` just add

```
/**
 A var to store CNContactStore
 */
let mContactStore = CNContactStore.init()
```

Inside `AppDelegate.swift` file.

And to use it anywhere just use this code

```
 contactStore = appDelegate.mContactStore
```

This will solve the issue for me and hopefully will solve the issue for you too.